# Use python to import/bulk-load into MS Access

Tags: python, ms-access, bulkinsert

Does anyone know a simple way to use python to load several CSV files into one given access table?

For example, my directory could have 100 files named import_*.csv  (import_1.csv, import_2.csv, etc)

There is one destination table in MS Access that should receive all of these csv's.

I know I could use pyodbc and build up statements line-by-line to do this, but that's a lot of coding.  You also then have to keep your SQL up-to-date as fields might get added or removed.   MS Access has it's own bulk load functionality - and I'm hoping that either this is accessible via python or that python has a library to that will do the same.

I would be fantastic if there is a library out there that could do it as easily as:

dbobj.connectOdbc( dsn )
dbobj.bulkLoad( "MyTable" , "c:/temp/test.csv" )

Internally it takes some work to figure out the schema and to make it work.  But hopefully someone out there has already done the heavy lifting?

Is there a way to do a bulk import?  Reading into pandas is trivial enough - but then you have to get it into MS Access from there.

Comment: Exporting from pandas to Access has already been shown here. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770412/5022913).

Comment: Ty.   These examples are what I don't want to do.   Let me edit my post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I'll take a crack at it.  So, you have 100+ CSV files in a directory and you want to push everything into MS Access.  Ok, I would combine all CSV files into one sight DF in Python, then save the DF, and import that into MS Access.

```
#1 Use Python to merge all CSV files into one single dataframe:
# Something like...

import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

#os.chdir("C:\\your_path_here\\")
results = pd.DataFrame([])
filelist = glob.glob("C:\\your_path_here\*.csv")
#dfList=[]
for filename in filelist:
    print(filename)  
    namedf = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=0, index_col=0)
    results = results.append(namedf)

results.to_csv('C:\\your_path_here\\Combinefile.csv')
```

Alternatively, and this is how I would to it...Use VBA in Access to consolidate all CSV files into one single table (no need, whatsoever, for Python).

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

    ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
    ' has field names
    blnHasFieldNames = False

    ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
    ' contains the CSV files
    strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

    ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
    ' the data are to be imported
    strTable = "tablename"

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
          DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, True

    ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
    ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
    '       Kill strPathFile
    strFile = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What I meant by bulk load was to easily import the table into Access without custom coding the SQL.   I never found another way...

Comment: I just gave you a way.  Did you actually try it?  I don't think so.