# Parameter error for pyodbc insert/apppend

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to insert/append into access a dataframe using pyodbc. However; when I run the code, I get an error: ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 21 parameter markers, but 1 parameter were supplied', 'HY000')

my sample code is: `for row in tDjango: cursor.execute( 'INSERT INTO TDjango (Eid, Eventtype, Location, Lat, Lon, Created, TMCClosed,FirstArrival(min), PatrolArrival(min), TowArrival(min), LanesCleared(min), RoadwayCleared(min),Camera, DayofWeekOpened, DayofWeekClosed, sameDay, confirmClosed, confirmFirstAr, confirmPtrl, confirmTow, confirmLnClear) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',tDjango)   conn.commit()`

I’m not entirely sure what I am missing in the SQL statement to make the error go away.

Comment: I can't find any example showing reference to dataframe in the execute argument. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767614/exporting-or-writing-data-from-python-pandas-data-frame-to-ms-access-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using cursor.execute(), I used cursor.executemany().